# I had a free Windows 10 upgrade and then my hard drive crashed

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10

I have another, older, laptop with a not-that-great hard drive in it (it's slow and I suspect vaguely compromised). My plan is to completely wipe this hard drive (it has Windows 7 (or Vista, I'll have to check--I haven't used it in a long time)) and put Windows 10 on it with my free upgrade, if I still have access to it somehow.

I also plan to put this hard drive (hopefully with Windows 10 on it) in my current laptop (the one with the crashed drive). From what I found browsing previously-answered questions on here, it seems I can do this hard drive swap, as long they both use Sata cords, which I'm pretty sure they do.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With Windows 10 Threshold 2, you can wipe the hard drive and then install windows 10 with your windows 7 product key. The product key should be on the back of the laptop.

I recommend that you upgrade to Windows 10 before the wipe. Also, windows vista/enterprise versions do not get the free upgrade.

Also, I would make sure that they are both the same size.

If the OS was installed on the broken hard drive, just repeat the steps using that laptop's product key.

FYI: check out media creation tool for an ISO or usb installation. If you choose a disk, it will make an ISO file which you will later have to burn to a disk. Make sure that the OS version you are using (enterprise, ultimate, pro) are the same as the edition the media is using. Windows 7 has more editions then windows 10 so Microsoft has a table of the upgrade (for example home premium is just home, and so is just home)